# How to target a class sevreal descendants down in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hide

I have several parent divs, each with a bunch of children. All of the parents contain a child (several divs deep) called .nxt

I want to hide all of the .nxt divs in the parent1 div, but not the other two parents.

Shouldn't

```
$('#parent1 .nxt').hide();
```

do it?

or do I need to include all the elements that lead down to .nxt

Thanks for your help.

Comment: show your html dom structure

Comment: That should do it, but why not just try it an see, should take less time than actually writing this question and asking us if it works or not?

Comment: I had been adeneo, but it wasn't working. A better question may have been - 'what is the correct way to target descendants?', but I knew my targeting was correct, which is why I asked the question I did.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind - it was working - I just had it BEFORE I'd actually added the parent1 div to the dom. Thanks guys.

Comment: as @adeneo said  you should try it first

Comment: I had tried it first. The problem wasn't directly related to my question - it was a placement error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('div:first').find('.nxt').hide();
```

[`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) will select the first elements  into matched set.